Determine which variables in dataframe are most correlated to two other variables
Say that I have a sample dataframe like so.
sample_df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

One thing you could ask is which columns in the dataframe are most correlated to column X1.  I know how to do this, with the following code below, which displays the top 5 correlations.
library(lares)
corr_var(sample_df,
  X1, 
  top = 5 
)

However, instead of just focusing on X1, I want to know which columns are most correlated to both X1 and X2. How could I do this?

Does most correlated to both mean you want to add the correlations and output one value or for each X1/X2 and then order both outputs separately? Maybe adding a desired output (on a smaller example) could help.

Yes, your first statement describes what I would like.

You can achieve your desired result with base R, e.g. sort(apply(cor(sample_df[,-(1:2)], sample_df[,1:2]), 1, \(x) sum(x)), decreasing=T)[1:5]. Not sure about lares::corr_var though.

@Andre Wildberg you may want to take absolute values before summing (see the-mad-satter's answer).

@Edward That may or may not be what OP wants. We don’t know the original data, so taking the absolute value of an anti-correlated value may lead to undesired (exaggerated) results.

@Andre Wildberg OP asked for most correlated, which can mean negative or positive. Negatively correlated is still correlated.

Using base R:
head(rev(sort(colSums(abs(cor(sample_df)[1:2, -c(1:2)])))),5)
      X28       X39       X42       X88       X76 
0.1223653 0.1214514 0.1158903 0.1146673 0.1104016


set.seed(42)
sample_df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))


Correlations range from -1 to 1 where values close to 0 imply little linear relationship and values further out imply increasing amounts of linear relationship.
Therefore, you might not want to simply add two correlations together as that might cancel out two strong correlations. Take for example the extreme case of -1 + 1 = 0.
Instead one idea would be to calculate the R2 value for each column as in Y ~ X1 + X2:
set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

r2_var <- function(data, ...) {
  x <- rlang::ensyms(...) |> as.character()
  y <- data |> base::names() |> base::setdiff(x)
  
  purrr::map(y, ~ {
    f <- base::sprintf("%s ~ %s", .x, base::paste(x, collapse = " + "))
    r2 <- base::summary(stats::lm(f, data))$r.squared
    dplyr::tibble(var = .x, r2 = r2)
  }) |>
    purrr::list_rbind() |>
    dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(r2))
}

r2_var(data, X1, X2)
#> # A tibble: 98 × 2
#>    var        r2
#>    <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 X28   0.00888
#>  2 X76   0.00810
#>  3 X42   0.00761
#>  4 X31   0.00741
#>  5 X39   0.00737
#>  6 X13   0.00678
#>  7 X88   0.00674
#>  8 X63   0.00600
#>  9 X81   0.00508
#> 10 X41   0.00470
#> # ℹ 88 more rows

Created on 2024-06-14 with reprex v2.1.0

map_dfr is superseded https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html and shouldn't be used.
